# UITouchのmajorRadiusというプロパティの単位 (iOS)

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c

Swift, Objective-Cについて質問です。
UITouchのmajorRadiusというプロパティの単位は何なのでしょうか?
タッチの面積(楕円の長径)を返すもののようですが、
pxなどの単位なのか疑問に思っています。

Answer (score 1):

ドキュメントにははっきりとこう書いてますね。

[majorRadius](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitouch/1618106-majorradius)

> ## majorRadius
>
> The radius (in **points**) of the touch.

iOSのプログラミングをしているなら「ポイント」(point)という単位はご存知かと思いますが、そのポイント単位ではかった半径(major radiusと言うのは日本語で言う長径の半分を表します)と言うことになります。

ただ、タッチセンサーの特性として、実際の接触面積を正確に測るのは難しいでしょうから、正確な値というよりは目安程度に考えた方が良いでしょう。実際にそのポイント数の半径の円を描くとかなりトンデモない大きさになってしまうこともあるようです。

Comment: ご回答どうもありがとうございます。ptが単位だったのですね。補足も参考にさせて頂きます。